Building One of Multiple Assemblies, Rerunning calculation in LINQPad (C#)
I have a solution with two assemblies.
The first assembly/project loads data from a database and caches it ("Data Assembly").
The second assembly/project performs calculations on the cached data ("Calculation Assembly").
My workflow is as follows:

Run a calculation calling a function in the Calculation Assembly - which triggers a bunch of data loads/caching by the Data Assembly.
When I run the calculation a second time, it's very fast since all of the data has been cached.
Then I make certain adjustments in the code of the Calculation Assembly, and build it again.
The issue: even though I didn't touch the Data Assembly's binary, if I run the same calculations again, all of my cached data in the Data Assembly has disappeared.

Not sure if this is LINQPad specific or generally a dotnet expected behavior: if assembly A references assembly B and it has been recompiled, everything has to be recreated in memory again.
Hope this is clear!


Not sure if this is LINQPad specific or generally a dotnet expected behavior: if assembly A references assembly B and it has been recompiled, everything has to be recreated in memory again.

This is a very,very basic description of what is happening.
Standard behaviour when you run any program (i.e. regardless of whether it is dotnet or not) is that you start a new 'process' and any memory allocated by your program for your variables is "owned" by that process. When the process stops, the operating system frees up all the memory owned by that process. Hence starting the same program will start from fresh (regardless of whether or not the program has changed).
Linqpad does things slightly differently in that when you run a script the first time it will start a new process, but (by default) it does not stop the process when your script has finished and so the memory is not released. So if you re-run your script, it is still running in the same process and hence still has access to static variables like your cache from the first run.
If you close your script, then this stops the process and hence frees up all the memory.
However, if you change your script in any way or change any of the dll's it uses, then Linqpad has no option but to stop the old process (otherwise it would still be running the old code). This means the memory used by the old process is freed up and so Linqpad will start a new process to run the script and, as you say, everything has to be recreated in memory again.
